# How to strip dashes except last dash out of file basename and display using php?

Tags: php

- My goal is simple, I have a url as `$url = 'example.com/bla-tla-bla.xyz';`
  and output of `basename($url)` is `bla-tla-bla.xyz`.
- Using `str_replace('-', ' ', basename($url))` I get `bla tla bla.xyz`.
  But my goal is bit different. I want it `bla tla-bla.xyz`.
- That means, I want to delete all dashes but not the last dashes and if possible then `bla tla- bla.xyz` - I mean a space after last dash. So what to do?

Comment: Have you used `substr` to break the string and apply the `str_replace` only to the front part?

Comment: That's all I did: `str_replace('-', ' ', basename($url))` and I am noob. Show me code, I hardly understand theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of **many** ways...

```
$rev = strrev(basename($url));
$bits = explode('-',$rev,2);
if (!empty($bits[1]))
   $bits[1] = str_replace('-', ' ', $bits[1]);
$result = strrev(implode("-",$bits));
```

Roundabout way to exploit the limit param for explode().

Comment: Will it work for bla-bla-bla-bla-bla.xyz to bla bla bla bla- bla.xyz?

Comment: Yes. Because of the limit to the explode, the last string ($bits[1]) contains ALL the remaining bits - in that example "bla-bla-bla-bla" which is then worked on by the str_replace

Comment: In addition, Can I make `bla tla- bla.xyz` to `bla tla_ bla.xyz`?

Comment: change the final implode()

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with *single expression*:

```
$source = 'bla-tla-bla.xyz';
$result = preg_replace(array('/-/', '/-(?=.*-)/'), array('- ', ''), $source);
```

This effectively applies two regular expressions; the first one replaces every dash with a dash+space, the second one removes all dashes which are *not* followed by other dashes.